# Identifying the variant of such a knapsack-like problem

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, integer-programming, knapsack

I am not too familiar with variants of knapsack problems (or variants of possibly other classical OR problems), but I would like to identify the following Integer Programming problem:
$$\min_{x_i,y_{i,j}} \sum_i c_i x_i$$

subject to  $$\sum_i y_{i,j} \le s_j \  \forall j $$
$$\sum_i u_{i,j} y_{i,j} \ge v \  \forall j $$
$$y_{i,j} \le x_i \  \forall j $$
$$x_i,y_{i,j} \in \{0,1\}.$$

Does this integer program belong to some sorts of variants of famous problems?

Comment: Welcome to OR SE. Should $u_{i,l}$ in your second constraint be $u_{i,j},$ and is $u$ a parameter (constant) versus a variable?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! My bad, it should be $u_{i,j}$. And yes, $u$ is a parameter. Only $x_i$ and $y_{i,j}$ are variables. @prubin

Comment: You can use multiple copies of an item, for example, $y_{i,0} = 1$, $y_{i,1} = 1$, but you cannot assign multiple copies to the same knapsack, since $y_{i,j}$ is binary. Is that right?

Comment: @fontanf Yes. That's correct!

Comment: Then I'm not aware of such problem in the literature (that doesn't mean there aren't). You have a cardinality constraint, there are a couple of papers about the "knapsack problem with cardinality constraint". And the objective can be interpreted as setup costs, and there are a couple of papers about the "knapsack problem with setups"

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a variant of the *minimum-weight multiset multicover problem* with the additional restriction that the required copies of item $j$ must be coverable by at most $s_j$ chosen multisets $i$.  What is the source of your problem?

Comment: It's my ongoing research project. You can think of $u_{i,j}$ as the utility of item $i$ to customer $j$, $x_{i}$ as the availability of item $i$, $y_{i,j}$ as the consumption of item $i$ by customer $j$, and $v$ is a certain utility threshold.